# GASの処理速度の違い

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

gasプロジェクトから直接スクリプトを実行する時と
トリガーやボタンを作成してスクリプトを割り当てて実行させた時を
比較して、処理速度は変わるものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

いままで処理速度が変わるような経験はありませんでした。
試しに以下コードを「直接実行」「トリガー」「ボタン」で各10回実行してみましたが明確な差はでませんでした。

```
function myFunction() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  for (var i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {};
  var endTime = new Date();
  var processTime = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;  // second
  Logger.log(processTime);
}
```

計測結果を添付します。
[image: 計測結果]

Comment: あの後、何回かた試してみて、実行時間にばらつきがあるように思えました。特にapiの呼び出しでばらつきが大きく感じられました

Comment: そうなんですね。もしかすると実行方法ではなくAPI自体にバラつきがあるのかもしれないですね。